# Good link for "how-to" ask questions in Ubuntu Forums

Tags: support

I am a rather new Linux user and I'm having several issues with Wi-Fi, Bluetooth and audio.

I have tried several solutions I found online to no affect. I would like to ask in the relevant Ubuntu forums but I'm not sure in which ones, what information to include (kernel version, cards model, `lspci`/`dmesg` output, etc...) Does someone have a good "How-To" ask for help in such fields for a newbie? Thanks!

Comment: Start with https://askubuntu.com/help. You seem to have multiple problems: Tackle problems one-at-a-time. Ask a separate question about each problem.  Provide terminal output: Show us *exactly* what you did and the complete result. It might look like jibberish to you, but it's vital clues to us. If you don't understand a term or a command, open a new browser tab and briefly ask your favorite Search Engine to explain it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! This is where you should ask any of your Ubuntu related questions. Here, you can learn [how to ask](https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask) properly before you do so. When asking a question, be sure you are [on topic](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic). This way, it's more likely volunteers on AU can help you.

Comment: Why did you format your links like that? You need to add the actual URL, not just write $SITEURL$. That does not work on SE at all and there is no meta.askubuntu help page, it is just on main, so even if it worked it would still fail because the links don't exist.

Comment: @MarkKirby. Sorry. I copy pasted it from my Auto Review Comments stackapp

Comment: Fair enough but better to just browse to the help and get the full link. I changed my vote.

Comment: @MarkKirby Thanks. I saw this q in review and it was low quality and I would have added the answer as a comment in usual procedings

Comment: Cool. Thanks!  :)
BTW- How do I find the where is it most relevant to ask a question? 
e.g. I have a Bluetooth problem with the recommended drivers installed. Where in Ask Ubuntu should I ask it? (or perhaps I should ask it in Ubuntu  Forums? I'm not a 100% sure about the differences)

Comment: @Charles You can ask anything related to Ubuntu here. Make sure you add appropriate tags. Cheers

Comment: @Charles "or perhaps I should ask it in Ubuntu Forums? I'm not a 100% sure about the differences"  See: https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1351/what-is-the-difference-between-ubuntuforums-and-askubuntu

Comment: Thank you all! :)