# Benefits of using Askubuntu versus Ubuntu Forum and what differs between both

Tags: discussion

A student today asked me when I told him to ask questions in AskUbuntu instead of the Ubuntu forums what did AskUbuntu offer instead of the forums in the Ubuntu site. I thought did would be a good question to ask here so to let people know what does one offer and what benefits do each bring to the community.

Basically what benefits does a user gain by using Askubuntu over the Ubuntu Forums (And vice versa) and what differs (what do each bring to the table) between both for the community.

Feel free to edit the title or move to another more related place just in case.

Comment: Jorge Castro's comment on the other site seems to have disappeared. Here's the link he posted. http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/234/why-this-over-the-ubuntu-forums

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Good question.

One of the things I really like about AskUbuntu is that is uses the Stack Exchange format.  Not only can you ask and answer questions, but the answers and questions can be both rated and commented on.  Having the ability to see what is the highest rated answer is a great help when trying to sort out the noise.  Many studies have shown that a group of people who reach a consensus often come up with better answers than someone working alone.

The biggest thing I think the Ubuntu Forums bring to the table is the depth of knowledge.  Topics there go back years, and there have been some good answers.

I also think that the Ubuntu Forums are still a bit more popular, but I haven't really checked.  Personally, I spend most of my time here, and once and a while refer people to answers in the Ubunutu Forums or Wiki.

That brings up another good point.  AskUbuntu is a Q/A format.  Ubuntu Forums are open to any relevant topic, not just Questions.

Comment: Also, the screen-dense format of allowing comments on the original question to be displayed immediately below the question, keeps the clarification questions at the top - no more buried duplicate clarifications. Better for new users and faster turn-around time. Less need to hunt for details.

Answer (score 8):

StackExchange sites allow answer collaboration. So if someone comes up with a good answer, but it isn't complete, other users can add on to it/correct it without fragmenting everything into numerous pages, forming one, complete answer.

Comment: Also a fantastic feature. Many users do not have English as their first language. The ability to edit questions and titles helps keep things focused.

Answer (score 0):

As for my experience the right hand does not know what the left does on askubuntu.com.
After had open a discussion I was first asked to not ask multiple questions in one thread. Well, are the rules here this way, I got it.
So, all my questions were into dedicated threads.
After that I am asked to not open multiple threads to ask same question.

Either they see all the questions address same topic, then they do not have to ask to 
stop asking multiple questions in one discussion. Or vice versa.

I am sure each my question over there addressed different topic. Therefore had followed the first request.

Furhtermore, as up to now I get on ubuntuforums accurate answers in shorter time.